# I am trying to change MYSQL 8.0 password using a shell script but its showing this error

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

error is "mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Please use --connect-expired-password option or invoke mysql in interactive mode.

Comment: It is a `warning`. not an `error`

Comment: After running script I get this ouput "Temporary Password is : m4BM!8ea2Ldy
Name of Database created is boat
New Root Password is dYBH1MvOPLkRt2qbLGMgL4LK
boat user password is h4s2SJkYRT1PEr8RFtKJ0Ban

mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Please use --connect-expired-password option or invoke mysql in interactive mode.
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Please use --connect-expired-password option or invoke mysql in interactive mode.
Enter password:"

Comment: What I have done is created a script where i am getting mysql's temporary password into a variable then creating a another password for root and then using this command "sudo mysql -u root -p${lt} -e "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${rootpswd}';" " to change the password

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore this hint, because it is considered unsafe to use mysql password in shell by default. You can

Comment: Yeah i want to ignore but after this warning the script wont go further it just ask me to enter password and says "Please use --connect-expired-password option or invoke mysql in interactive mode."

Comment: @goku You can write the password as a variable in the shell script and assign it. You can also post other mistakes.

Comment: I have done exactly what you said but it still show only one thing tha is "Please use --connect-expired-password option or invoke mysql in interactive mode. " and after this message scripts exits.

Answer (score 0):

The warning should not be ignored *in production systems*; ref. https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/798.html

I do not understand why "exit" is relevant, nor do I know if this is your issue; but I suspect this is a real bug (the mysql folks might have assumed all systems are in production), so you should probably push back on this yourself directly--see https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103383.

Here is one strange solution: https://www.looklinux.com/mysql-warning-using-a-password-on-the-command-line-interface-can-be-insecure/